# Android Studio - How to ( close, quit, exit, kill, etc.) an application

Tags: android

Firstly, I've tried almost all the solutions about this issue but I can not find solution.

**Question:**  When user press exit button in my application I want to kill all application. There is a few methods like **finish();** or **System.exit(0);**
If I use on MainActivity, they are work. I want this, If I MainActivity or A Activity or B Activity doesnt matter which Activty when I press exit button just kill all application and go back phones menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
finishAffinity();
```

Check this for deails: [API Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity%28%29)

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in
>   the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used
>   when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from
>   an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used
>   the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own
>   task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other
>   activities of the second application, all of those should be removed
>   from the original task as part of the task switch.
>
> Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying
>   to do so.

Comment: `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);`